# Requesting data using API Confusion between GET and POST | Is this curl get secure to use?

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I'm using this to request some data from an API:

```
<?php

$query = "https://somewebsite.com/apiv2/customer.stats.json?api_user=USERNAME&api_key=PASSWORD@&user=SUBUSER";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $query
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;

?>
```

Now, the variable $query contains an URL, and this URL has usernames and passwords. The method above uses GET, can it leak data while it is processing?

Sorry I'm just learning. I know that it would be safer to use POST when dealing with sensitive information, put I thought that we should use post only when we plan to change something. In this case, I'm just consulting data, without change anything, so in my head I can't use POST. This is confusing me.

Can some one please explain? It will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: though you are using SSL so your data cannot be tampered in its way to the server, remember that query strings are stored in the server request logs, therefore visible for anyone having access to the logs. If the server gets hacked, well, you can figure the rest :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll fix that right now :).

Answer (score 1):

In CURL, Your `URL` and `PARAMETERS` should be separate. Use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` in your options and a base URL for your `CURLOPT_URL`

Edit: You might also want to consider setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `true`.

Comment: Not an issue, but not necessarily good practice to have arguments in a URL for curl.

Comment: I will set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to true, thank you.
But how can I use parameters in the URL? Could you explain it to me? I don't want to have the username and password in the URL.

Comment: Curl will still compile the final request, especially if this is a GET request. You simply use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and set it to `key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3`.

Comment: PS: You should consider yourself lucky you don't have to use OAuth2 to access this API. A lot of people are starting to use it... and I hate it (personally).

Comment: Oh I think I got it, I'll try to do it and then I post here if I managed to get it working.

Comment: by the way, you say you don't want the username and password in the url - it's going to have to end up there eventually. If you control the app on the server, you can do other things, like signing the request instead (include a timestamp, and check the timestamp on receipt!). Then you dont have to transmit the creds. at all.

Answer (score 0):

The data in question will be stored in memory - that is inevitable. That is not a security risk in general.

The connection uses https, so it will not be exposed while connecting to the server - this is good!

I can see no validation of the certificate of the https, so anyone who gets control of the network between you and them (not simple, but not impossible) could pretend to be the server, and collect the information. Not good.

Your script has a plaintext password in it. If anyone can download your script, they have your password. Not good, but very difficult to avoid.

Your "settings" (username and password) should be separate from the URL, for readability. Not a security risk, but bad programming practice.

In response to your comment, to keep the username & password separate, you could do this:

```
$username='bob';
$password='s3kr3t!';
$subuser='matty';
$url="http://...?this=$username&password=$password...";
```

Or, you could make it even tidier:

```
$creds=Array(
    "api_user"=>"bob",
    "api_key"=>"1234",
    "user=subuser"
);
$url="http://google.com/?"+http_build_query($creds);
```

Comment: How could I have the settings separate from the URL? I know this is a dumb question, I guessed that I could use "https://somewebsite.com/apiv2/customer.stats.json?api_user=$user&api_key=$password@&user=SUBUSER"; but well, obviously I can't :/